# Dynamic binding to property

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Hi i am using entity framework as my mapper, i have dropDownList and i want to set up in code behinde DataTextField to some property of my class, but i don't want to do it static with "someProperty" cos if there will change field in my model, this place will trow me exception. How can i do it , that if property name will change, here the binding will point at changed property?

i found much better solution:

```
public static string GetPropertyName<T, TReturn>(Expression<Func<T, TReturn>> expression)
    {
        MemberExpression body = (MemberExpression)expression.Body;
        return body.Member.Name;
    }
```

and then:

```
GetPropertyName((SampleClass) => r.SampleProperty)
```

so this is not static string, but i am still not happy cos when i change the filed in entity model, here i have an error, is this possbile that with changes in model , this binding will change too?

Comment: No, that's not possible. When your model changes you have to update your code to use the new property name etc.
btw your solution really is really nice to eliminate the need to have a hardcoded string :)

Answer (score 0):

We are mapping the business objects to anonymous objects before databinding, like this:

```
var objectsToBindToDropdown = businessObjects.Select(o => new 
    {
        SomeProperty1 = o.BusinessProperty1, 
        SomeProperty2 = o.BusinessProperty2
    });

dropDownList.DataTextField  = "SomeProperty1";
// TODO: bind the drop down list
```

If there is a change in the model, e.g. BusinessProperty1 is renamed to AnotherBusinessProperty1, you will get compilation error, and that was exactly the goal.